# Adam optimizer between Tf 1 and Tf 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow1.15

I am trying to replicate the same result between Tf1 and Tf2. In below, there is a simple example using Adam optimizer.

Here in TF2:

```
x = tf.Variable([1,2,3], dtype=tf.float32)
grad = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.5, epsilon=1e-08)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grad], [x]))
print(x)
```

x is:
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.49998665, 1.4999859 , 2.4999857 ], dtype=float32)>

While in TF1:

```
x = tf.Variable([1,2,3], dtype=tf.float32)
grad = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grad], [x]))

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  print(sess.run(x))
```

x is:
[1. 2. 3.]

Does anyone know what causes inconsistencies between Tf1 and Tf2 when using Adam Optimizer? I do not exclude the possibility of a wrong implementation.

I would appreciate it a lot if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong in TF1 that I cannot get the same result as in TF2.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instead do this:

```
x = tf.Variable([1,2,3], dtype=tf.float32)
grad = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5)
step = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grad], [x]))

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  sess.run(step)
  print(x.eval())
```

You get the same result (barring what I think could be floating point inaccuracies).

```
[0.50000155 1.5000007  2.5000005 ]
```

Comment: I see the issue! Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reproducibility is a tricky yet crucial step in commercial AI/ML projects.

Heres the v1 implementation of Adam on GH: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4c081973a6374ce867794ad66a5c4b204c310afb/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v1.py#L468

And here’s the v2 one: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.7.0/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py

They are implemented slightly differently. I found this in the V2 documentation:
Many optimizer subclasses, such as `Adam` and `Adagrad` allocate and manage additional variables associated with the variables to train.  These are called  *Slots*.  Slots have names and you can ask the optimizer for the names of the slots that it uses.  Once you have a slot name you can ask the optimizer for the variable it created to hold the slot value.

Also if you’re trying to migrate code from 1 to 2 you can do it automatically as per https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, for your explanation. I read through all the links that you provided, and they were very helpful considering the whole scope of the project. However, in the provided example, I still do not understand why I am getting two different results, using the same functions. Those examples were provided here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py